# HTML and jQuery anchoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

Whenever the url contains the div id, it would obviously go down to the div when the URL has:

> http://domain.com.faq.php#1

```
<div id="1">Bla bla bla</div>
```

But what I like is to have same feature of Stackoverflow, when you click on an answer in your messages, it will scroll down to the page and has that fadeOut effect on the answer.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't know jQuery effects well enough to actually answer this, but basically, use the [`ready` function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to do some processing on page load, and in your handler, read `window.location.hash` to find out which (if any) element to highlight, and then do the effect you want. You probably don't actually want to fade in (since the element will already be showing); SO, for instance, just fades in a different background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animation to a valid anchor destination *cannot* be animated on page load that I know of since the browsers will default to scrolling the user down the page to the anchor. For in-page links, you can hijack the anchor links and animate.

However, on new page loads like on SO, you will notice the page does not *animate* down, but just scrolls down, though the box does animate a color. This is how you could do it in jQuery. Be sure to include the [`color`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin if you want to animate background-colors.

```
<script src="js/jquery.color.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if(hash){
          $(hash).css('backgroundColor', '#AA0000')
                 .animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}, 200);
        }
   });
</script>
```

You can use DOMReady instead of load, but it might try to run your animation too soon, and the user will miss it.

If you only wanted to animate `div`'s with a specific class, you can add a filter to your find:

```
$(hash).filter('.my_div').css ...
```

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow uses anchors as well.  The post you're currently reading is:
[HTML and jQuery anchoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945207/html-and-jquery-anchoring/2945227#2945227)

It's simply `<a name="anchorName"></a>`
at the address bar: [urlToPage]#anchorName

---

Now, to get the fade effect [in pure JS w/o frameworks]

Set the div.style.opacity = 0;

```
var intervalId = setInterval( function(){
  if( (div.style.opacity+= 0.1) >= 1) clearInterval(intervalId);
}, millisecondInterval);
```

The clearInterval part isn't necessary, since once opacity goes above 1, browser won't render differently [although the number keeps adding...]

Comment: I think you've missed the central part of his question: The effect.

Comment: Hey, `link` should be `href` in your `<a>` tag, and giving a pure JS answer to a jQuery specific question makes this a poor answer. -1

Comment: @Doug Neiner, He didn't specify JQuery only, he only tagged it with JQuery AND JavaScript.  I've seen many questions tagged with JQuery, Mootools, etc.  Doesn't mean that the answer must use those frameworks.  As for link, I meant name, to define an anchor point.

Comment: I realize that sometimes it is the case, but the question title is "HTML and *jQuery* anchoring" with a tag of jQuery... dunno, I guess I read "better" into the words "pure JS" and for someone using jQuery which already works to normalize browser diferences, it seems better to give the answer in jQuery. Now that the `a` part is right, I removed the -1. Sorry if I over thought it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

For example:

```
$('li.share a').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var link = ev.target.href;
        var id = link.substring(link.indexOf("#") + 1);
        $('#' + id).fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: `fadeOut` will make the answer disappear, which seems...non-optimal.

Comment: Sure, but that's what he asked for ;-) You're right. I would prefer `$('#' + id).toggle();` or `$('#' + id).slideToggle();`.